# C# .Net SIMD System.Numerics.Vector4 slower than loop

Tags: c#, vectorization, simd

I wrote the following code to experiment with System.Numerics.Vector4 and evaluate the performance gain:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Numerics;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int N = 100000000;
            long ticks_start, ticks_end;

            ticks_start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

            float[] a = { 10, 10, 10, 10 };
            float[] b = new float[4];

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
                    b[j] = a[j] + a[j];

            ticks_end = DateTime.Now.Ticks;


            Console.WriteLine($"Done in {ticks_end - ticks_start} ticks");

            ticks_start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

            Vector4 result;
            Vector4 v = new Vector4();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                v.W = a[0];
                v.X = a[1];
                v.Y = a[2];
                v.Z = a[3];
                result = Vector4.Add(v, v);
                b[0] = result.W;
                b[1] = result.X;
                b[2] = result.Y;
                b[3] = result.Z;
            }
            ticks_end = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            Console.WriteLine($"Done in {ticks_end - ticks_start} ticks");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Done in 14257591 ticks
Done in 18591588 ticks
```

So it seems that we get no advantage using Vector4. The Add method returns a new instance of Vector4. Is there a way to mutate one of the vectors to avoid the memory allocation impact? Or maybe there is another way to do things?

Comment: When you ran the same test with benchmark.net, what did you find?

Comment: Also can you clarify what you mean "allocation impact" for `struct`?

Comment: Why are you including statements to unpack the array into a vector, then back again, on every single loop iteration? In realistic applications you would keep everything in vectors while calculating. Microbenchmarks are always hazardous even if performed with proper code (which, as mjwills notes, benchmark.net offers) but in this case it's especially important to benchmark a realistic scenario. A single 4-element vector addition with lots of memory movement surrounding it is not.

Comment: @mjwills it is totally reasonable to expect code that does more operations to be slower - what may be surprising is that the difference is so small for copying values into a struct first and than calling a method with large size parameters and copying results back...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I mean that each addition causes a new instance of Vector4 to be created, thereby allocating memory and incurring the cost of such allocation.

Comment: @mjwills Did not do a benchmark using this tool. Working on company machine and cannot install software.

Comment: @Tarik allocating memory where? There should be zero dynamic allocations in that code... as stack will be pre-allocated at compile time... Not really sure what you mean "allocating memory and incurring the cost of such allocation"...

Comment: [benchmarkdotnet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/benchmark.net) is not a tool but a NuGet package. Unless the machine is locked down to the point where even NuGet is inaccessible (which I image would complicate development a lot) you can use it. If NuGet *is* inaccessible, I imagine you're not testing this on .NET Core either. (The performance differences between Core and Framework are notable, especially for SIMD intrinsincs.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Well, being realistic is what I was looking at. I assumed a scenario where I got a large array of floats that I would like to double in value. The only way to do it with Vector4 is to pack and unpack. Essentially, you are telling me that the only viable way to use this is to change my data structure in terms of Vector4 to avoid packing and unpacking.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I mean this `result = Vector4.Add(v, v);` will cause a `Vector4` to be created at each loop, then assigned to `result` variable.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I should have said library, sorry. No access to NuGet for security reasons.

Comment: The perf benefits of SIMD are typically huge enough that you don't care that you have vectors all over the place for the calculations and arrays only at the very beginning and end. Note however that recent versions of .NET Core include autovectorization optimizations out of the box, meaning that even a plain array add loop may be converted to use SIMD instructions effectively. [Demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgxgewHYWAAgJZPQOTQXjQEYAGM8sgbgFgAoOgMwBsExgBtAXTTALQG9iJADRDRpcSTQBfGrWasO3AEZ8kAUwDuaBW3YAWTnMYIATmgAUWdBj4lKmNAB40OBxgDUHgJR00/nTNLazQAKzsHcJd9SK9fWgDEtGV2UO5CMFTuDx4s41ogA).

Comment: @JeroenMostert ".NET Core include autovectorization optimizations out of the box, meaning that even a plain array add loop may be converted to use SIMD intstructions effectively" OK, then this whole explicit vectorization makes no sense. "The perf benefits of SIMD are typically huge enough that you don't care that you have vectors all over the place for the calculations and arrays only at the very beginning and end." Well, if a program is already written and uses a Point class or something similar, it might be quite costly to have to switch to Vector4 all over the application.

Comment: @Tarik somehow the fact that *exactly the same* thing happens with your first loop (a double created every time at each loop on `a[j] + a[j];`) is fine for you... (it's somewhat rude of me to think that you have no idea what `new Vector4()` actually mean... but maybe you should read about `struct` in C#).

Comment: Explicit vectorization may well make no sense for this particular, very simple scenario, no. If the compiler autovectorizes your loop you're comparing one vectorization to another. Of course there are less trivial scenarios where the compiler doesn't recognize that what you're doing can be vectorized, and then explicit vectorization can help. (`Numerics` also largely precedes the major autovectorization efforts; explicit vectorization used to be the only thing available.)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Ah, ok, thanks for pointing this out. I now understand that struct is treated as a value type and consequently does not cause any allocation. OK, my bad :-) Programming since 1985 but still learning. Ego is my least concern Alexei, too old for that at 56.

Comment: @JeroenMostert "(Numerics also largely precedes the major autovectorization efforts; explicit vectorization used to be the only thing available." It crossed my mind. I should have said "at this point in time...". Meanwhile, using explicit vectorization seem to force us to adapt the application data structure. I am not trying to argue just for the sake of it. I am trying to figure out a correct use case for this functionality out of pure curiosity. An simple example would be welcome. My attempt at creating a simple example failed and brought me on S.O.

Comment: Debug/Release build?

Comment: your benchmark is flawed. I believed it'll be optimized out completely in release mode. Benchmarking in C# is very hard because you'll have to warm up first and do many things to avoid effects like decompilation. Use a proper microbenchmark library instead

Comment: @phuclv Will run from the command line in release mode and come back. The code is simple and I am looping 100 million times, enough to offset warmup or whatever.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Using release mode did the trick. The vectorized version is about 25% faster.

Comment: @phuclv Release mode worked faster

Comment: @Tarik That's where they eliminate "useless" assign/memory consumption. Could you run the performance comparison again? So we can compare numbers?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Will do when back in my office on Sunday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't really benchmarked it, but this, in the inner loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{

    v.W = a[0];
    v.X = a[1];
    v.Y = a[2];
    v.Z = a[3];
    result = Vector4.Add(v, v);
    b[0] = result.W;
    b[1] = result.X;
    b[2] = result.Y;
    b[3] = result.Z;
}
```

Would be more equivalent to:

```
float[] a = { 10, 10, 10, 10 };
float[] b = new float[4];
float[] v = new float[4];
float[] result = new float[4];

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    v[0] = a[0];
    v[1] = a[1];
    v[2] = a[2];
    v[3] = a[3];
    result[0] = v[0] + v[0];
    result[1] = v[1] + v[1];
    result[2] = v[2] + v[2];
    result[3] = v[3] + v[3];
    b[0] = result[0];
    b[1] = result[1];
    b[2] = result[2];
    b[3] = result[3];
}
```

Than what you've written (you are making 4 assignations -assigning to `v`-, then the addition, then another 4 assignations -assigning `result` to `b`-, which you are just skipping on your array operation).

I just tested it on linqpad using stopwatches (this is by no means a benchmark), and if you do this, it's slower with the array addition (even with the sum unrolled) than it is with `Vector4` (by a very tight margin).

Comment: In release mode, the vectorized version is faster.

Answer (score 2):

As per various advices in the comment section, tested in release mode and the vectorized version is significantly faster than the array version.

**This answer is posted for better visibility. Credits to go to Jeroen van Langen, phuclv and Alexei Levenkov.**

Thanks both for their time and patience answering this question.

Answer (score 1):

The code can be improved using no allocations. `MemoryMarshal.Cast` literally creates a `Span` that points to the same memory area as array. The size of the `float` array can be any, it will produce `Span` of size `a.Length / 4` of `Vector4`.

The same with result. When you're writing to the output `Span`, the data being written to the output array memory area directly.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int N = 100000000;
    long ticks_start, ticks_end;

    ticks_start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

    float[] a = { 10, 10, 10, 10 };
    float[] b = new float[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            b[j] = a[j] + a[j];

    ticks_end = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", b));
    Console.WriteLine($"Done in {ticks_end - ticks_start} ticks");

    Console.WriteLine("Clearing...");
    Array.Clear(b, 0, b.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", b));


    ticks_start = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

    ReadOnlySpan<Vector4> v = MemoryMarshal.Cast<float, Vector4>(a);
    Span<Vector4> r = MemoryMarshal.Cast<float, Vector4>(b);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        r[0] = Vector4.Add(v[0], v[0]);
    }

    ticks_end = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", b));
    Console.WriteLine($"Done in {ticks_end - ticks_start} ticks");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Running Release build.

```
20, 20, 20, 20
Done in 2172911 ticks
Clearing...
0, 0, 0, 0
20, 20, 20, 20
Done in 649113 ticks
```

Looks like 3.3x times faster.